# Serializing a nested namedtuple into JSON with Python >= 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, namedtuple

I have a problem similar to [CalvinKrishy's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906831/serializing-a-python-namedtuple-to-json)
Samplebias's solution is not working with the data I have.

I am using Python 2.7.

Here's the data:

#### Namedtuple

```
>>> a_t = namedtuple('a','f1 words')
>>> word_t = namedtuple('word','f2 value')
>>> w1 = word_t(f2=[0,1,2], value='abc')
>>> w2 = word_t(f2=[3,4], value='def')
>>> a1 = a_t(f1=[0,1,2,3,4],words=[w1, w2])
>>> a1
a(f1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], words=[word(f2=[0, 1, 2], value='abc'), word(f2=[3, 4], value='def')])
```

#### Dict

```
>>> w3 = {}
>>> w3['f2'] = [0,1,2]
>>> w3['value'] = 'abc'
>>> w4 = {}
>>> w4['f2'] = [3,4]
>>> w4['value'] = 'def'
>>> a2 = {}
>>> a2['f1'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a2['words'] = [w3,w4]
>>> a2
{'f1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'words': [{'f2': [0, 1, 2], 'value': 'abc'}, {'f2': [3, 4], 'value': 'def'}]}
```

As you can see that both a1 and a2 are same except that one is **namedtuple** and other is **dict**.

But the json.dumps is different:

```
>>> json.dumps(a1._asdict())
'{"f1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], "words": [[[0, 1, 2], "abc"], [[3, 4], "def"]]}'
>>> json.dumps(a2)
'{"f1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], "words": [{"f2": [0, 1, 2], "value": "abc"}, {"f2": [3, 4], "value": "def"}]}'
```

I want to have json format of a1 exactly like its doing for a2.

Comment: A namedtuple is a subclass of tuple, so JSON serialises those as lists, as it should.

Comment: but http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict

returns an OrderedDict

Comment: That is a utility method; convert your tuples to ordered dicts then first before serialising to JSON.

Comment: You could create custom subclass of the encoder to handle named tuples: [Overriding nested JSON encoding of inherited default supported objects like dict, list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16361223)

Comment: @MartijnPieters you can't override the json encoder's behavior in this case, as it sees namedtuples as tuples.

Comment: @Emil: see the linked post, it deals with just that; overriding the default behaviour.

Comment: I suggest to [use a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906831/serializing-a-python-namedtuple-to-json/52224472#52224472).

Answer (score 13):

The problem is in the use of `namedtuple._asdict`, not `json.dumps`. If you look at the code with `namedtuple(..., verbose=True)` you will see this:

```
def _asdict(self):
    'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values'
    return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))
```

Only the *top level* is actually changed into an OrderedDict, all contained elements are left untouched. This means that nested `namedtuple`s still are `tuple` subclasses and get (correctly) serialized and such.

If the call to a specific conversion function is acceptable for you (like the call to `_asdict`), you can write your own one.

```
def namedtuple_asdict(obj):
  if hasattr(obj, "_asdict"): # detect namedtuple
    return OrderedDict(zip(obj._fields, (namedtuple_asdict(item) for item in obj)))
  elif isinstance(obj, basestring): # iterables - strings
     return obj
  elif hasattr(obj, "keys"): # iterables - mapping
     return OrderedDict(zip(obj.keys(), (namedtuple_asdict(item) for item in obj.values())))
  elif hasattr(obj, "__iter__"): # iterables - sequence
     return type(obj)((namedtuple_asdict(item) for item in obj))
  else: # non-iterable cannot contain namedtuples
    return obj

json.dumps(namedtuple_asdict(a1))
# prints '{"f1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], "words": [{"f2": [0, 1, 2], "value": "abc"}, {"f2": [3, 4], "value": "def"}]}'
```

As you can see, the biggest problem is having nested structures which are *not* `namedtuple`s but could contain them.

Comment: Just a bit of warning: this function is not safe for any circular data structures.

Comment: For Python 3 replace `basestring` with `str` in the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the version I went with, adapted from MisterMiyagi's. I used `isinstance` with `collections.abc` instead of `hasattr`, and I incuded a `_type` key in the resulting dict with the name of the namedtuple class.

```
import collections.abc

def _nt_to_dict(obj):
    recurse = lambda x: map(_nt_to_dict, x)
    obj_is = lambda x: isinstance(obj, x)
    if obj_is(tuple) and hasattr(obj, '_fields'):  # namedtuple
        fields = zip(obj._fields, recurse(obj))
        class_name = obj.__class__.__name__
        return dict(fields, **{'_type': class_name})
    elif obj_is(collections.abc.Mapping):
        return type(obj)(zip(obj.keys(), recurse(obj.values())))
    elif obj_is(collections.abc.Iterable) and not obj_is(str):
        return type(obj)(recurse(obj))
    else:
        return obj
```