# Custom formatting for just a portion of data during JSON serialization

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization, json-serialization

I have a Python object tree I want to serialize. Its structure is something like this:

```py
{
    "regular_object": {
        ...
    },
    "regular_field": ...
    "special_object": {
        "f1": "v1",
        "f2": v2,
        ...
        "fn": "vn"
    }
}
```

I wanna serialize such object tree so that it's formatted like this in a JSON representation:

```py
{
    "regular_object": {
        ...
    },
    "regular_field": ...
    "special_object": { "f1": "v1", "f2": v2, ..., "fn": "vn" }
}
```

In other words, I want *mixed formatting based on the contents of the object being formatted*.

I tried playing around with `json.JSONEncoder` by overriding its `default` method and using a custom class object for storing the `special_object`'s contents so that the custom `default` is called, something like this:

```py
class SpecialObject:
    def __init__(self, attrs: dict):
        self.attrs = attrs

class SpecialEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        JE = json.JSONEncoder
        if isinstance(o, SpecialObject):
            return f"{{ ', '.join([f'{JE.encode(self, el[0])}: {JE.encode(el[1])}' for el in o.attrs.items()]) }}"
        else:
            return super().default(o)
```

But it looks like `JSONEncoder` encodes the `default`'s return value *again*, so the string I generate for my custom type gets serialized as a string, with the output being something like:

```py
{
    ...
    "special_object": "{ \"f1\": \"v1\", ..., \"fn\": \"vn\" }"
}
```

which is clearly not what I had in mind. I also tried overriding the `JSONEncoder.encode` method like some answers here suggest, but that method never gets invoked from within `JSONEncoder` itself.

I did find [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361223/overriding-nested-json-encoding-of-inherited-default-supported-objects-like-dict) [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405969/how-to-change-json-encoding-behaviour-for-serializable-python-object) to solving seemingly similar problems, but the solutions presented there are way too monstrously looking and overly complex for a task like mine.
Is there a way to achieve what I need in just one-two dozen lines of code without going too deep into `JSONEncoder`'s intestines? It does not need to be a generic solution, just something I could fix quickly and which may work for a single case only.

Comment: Your desired output is not JSON.

Comment: @Goyo, how is that? It's somewhere in between the docs' examples for pretty printing and compact printing

Comment: Because any JSON parser will fail at parsing it. I do not understand what you say about the examples.

Comment: @Goyo, [are you sure](https://repl.it/repls/PaleUnfortunateDecompilers)?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Then the lack of quotes around `v2` is just an overlook and we are just talking about newlines here?

Comment: @Goyo, i think it's pretty clear that example of json is just a random example which doesn't pretend to be 100% valid.

Comment: @OlvinRoght That's pretty clear to me too, but what parts are supposed to be valid wasn't so clear.

Comment: @Goyo, well, to be honest, the `v2` case is for the types like numbers which do not have to be quoted.

Comment: So does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can do something like this, but it's ***...*** you see how it looks.

```
def custom_json_dumps(obj, *args, keys_to_skip_indent=(), **kwargs):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        indent = kwargs.pop("indent", 0)
        separators = kwargs.get("separators", (", ", ": "))

        res = "{" + "\n" * int(indent != 0)
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k in keys_to_skip_indent or indent == 0:
                encoded = json.dumps(v, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                encoded = json.dumps(v, *args, indent=indent, **kwargs)
            res += "\"{}\"".format(k) + separators[1] + encoded + separators[0] + "\n" * int(indent != 0)

        return res[:res.rindex(separators[0])].replace("\n", "\n" + " " * indent) + "\n" * int(indent != 0) + "}"
    else:
        return json.dumps(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Test:**

```
o = {
    "regular_object": {
        "a": "b"
    },
    "regular_field": 100000,
    "float_test": 1.0000001,
    "bool_test": True,
    "list_test": ["1", 0, 1.32, {"a": "b"}],
    "special_object": {
        "f1": "v1",
        "f2": "v2",
        "fn": "vn"
    }
}

print(custom_json_dumps(o, keys_to_skip_indent={"special_object",  "list_test"}, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "regular_object": {
        "a": "b"
    }, 
    "regular_field": 100000, 
    "float_test": 1.0000001, 
    "bool_test": true, 
    "list_test": ["1", 0, 1.32, {"a": "b"}], 
    "special_object": {"f1": "v1", "f2": "v2", "fn": "vn"}
}
```

Comment: It's not pretty, basically a manual labor, but in the absence of a better solution it will do. Thanks for the effort =)

Comment: @Semisonic, there is another "correct" solution with subclassing JSONEncoder and overriding couple of methods, but It will be easily 10 times more code. If somebody interested, how to do it properly, I can add it to post.

Comment: I think `indent = kwargs.pop("indent", 0)` would save you a couple of lines of code while making your intent more obvious.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, if your "proper" solution does not require reverse engineering the JSONEncoder's internals, it would be interesting to see. But, judging by the answers to similar questions I found here, it doesn't seem possible.